# Cannot set Thunderbird as default app for "mailto"

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, thunderbird, mailto

I use Firefox and Thunderbird under Ubuntu for many years now. Since a couple of months, I cannot open a link to a mail on Firefox as, when I click on a link of a mail, it tries to open Chrome!
I have tried to manually set Thunderbird, but it does not work and if I set the option on "always ask", the link to Thunderbird does not work.
Any idea what I could do?

Cheers

Comment: It might be that Chrome is setting itself as the default mail application each time it runs. See https://ladedu.com/how-to-change-the-default-email-program-in-google-chrome/ , for example. To me, that seems pernicious for the browser to change user settings.